# Require to create example questions before allowing to create a site proposal

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I see many new proposals on Area51, where the authors even don't care to provide any example question.

I don't know what's the agenda behind it. Do those people simply have some concept of the site, but no idea how to deal with it, or do they just want to game some reputation or become "famous" as site creators... But such proposals are often very misleading, and gather no activity or some passive followers.

I think it should be author's obligation to create 5 example questions and that obligation should be enforced on start. Before the proposal can be submitted, it should be required that the author creates 5 example questions for it.

Well, maybe 3 is enough. But it should not be possible to create a proposal without any question. Anyone can create a site proposal, so if you have no idea what you could ask, please leave the honour of creating it to someone more worthy.